# How do I find a more descriptive XML Path for my Selenium webscrape?

Tags: python, xml, selenium

I'm building a website scraper using Selenium and I want to "click" the highlighted div in the image below.

[image: Website's HTML]

My current code (which works, but isn't very descriptive) is:

```
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[5]/div[8]")
button.click()
```

I'm glad it works, but it feels fragile, since I'm accessing the divs purely by index, without any other identifying features.  Is there a way, at least for the last div, that I can specify my choice by the text within span?  What would the syntax be for choosing the div that contains a span with the text "Grandmaster"?

It's worth noting that this is the only div in any of the "filter-group"s that contains the text "Grandmaster".  Is there a way to select this div specifically, without listing all the nested divs (as I've done in my code above)?

Any other ideas on how to make the XML path's code a bit more robust would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What would the syntax be for choosing the div that contains a span
>   with the text "Grandmaster"?

You can use this `xPath`:

```
//span[contains(., 'Grandmaster')]/parent::div
```

more information you can get [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp).

Answer (score 2):

> What would the syntax be for choosing the div that contains a span with the text "Grandmaster"?

The syntax would be:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Grandmaster')]")
```

Comment: Works well, just needed to change to "find_element_by_xpath", rather than "find_elements_by_xpath".  (The latter returns a list.)  Thanks.

Comment: @Camoen fixed it